# How to proper create a custom cell with a xib file, register, and load it ?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

## I want

to create a custom table cell and add all the components and register it

## I did

I created these files below :

[image]

**PlaceDetailCell.xib** 
with the *id* of `customPlaceDetailCell`

[image]

**CustomPlaceDetailCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomPlaceDetailCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var country: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

## I register

```
//register xib file
    placesTable.register(UINib(nibName: "PlaceDetailCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customPlaceDetailCell")
```

This is my **cellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customPlaceDetailCell", for: indexPath)
     as! CustomPlaceDetailCell

    if places[indexPath.row]["name"] != nil {
        cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]! + " (" + distances[indexPath.row] + " miles)"
    }

    return cell
}
```

## I got

a crash when I click on that cell even if the app is successfully Build.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key address.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

## I hope

someone can provide some guidance for me to do the right things.

Comment: Did you set the class of the cell in the xib file? If you did, double check the module.

Comment: Check the class of the cell in Interface Builder. Double-check that your outlets are connected properly.  `cell.textLabel` isn't defined.

Comment: Can you check if you did connect properly the outlets? And also make sure that you didn't connect them as File's Owner.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez :  It was set to wrong class, now I set it to `CustomPlaceDetailCell` : https://i.imgur.com/U3hJK0b.png

Comment: @EmilioPelaez ater updating the class seems to load and working perfectly fine;

Comment: @DionizB after update the class, look like the outlets link correctly now, the circled seems filled : https://i.imgur.com/fdnmr3L.png

Comment: @JonJ : I think I connected it properly now https://i.imgur.com/fdnmr3L.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the xib file custom class to the class you cast it to

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customPlaceDetailCell", for: indexPath)
 as! CustomPlaceDetailCell
```

as it seems that xib name is `PlaceDetailCell` with class `PlaceDetailCell` and you cast it to `CustomPlaceDetailCell`

if you register this

```
 placesTable.register(UINib(nibName: "PlaceDetailCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customPlaceDetailCell")
```

then the xib custom class should be set to `CustomPlaceDetailCell` not to `PlaceDetailCell` which is expected as always the xib name = it's class name that you create and then wanted to change the class name

Comment: My issue is I forgot to add a class to my .xib file. I don't really need to change anything in my **cellForRowAt** function. This is what I have now : https://i.imgur.com/ZJaM0Ju.png

Comment: not saying to change in cellForRowAt , I'm illustrating that what you cast the **tableView.dequeueReusableCell** to should be the class name in xib

Comment: I don't get you still. I think I did it and cast it as what you proposing already.

Comment: Read this in last block in answer **then the xib custom class should be set to CustomPlaceDetailCell not to PlaceDetailCell**